# How do i correctly enter a Decimal Type through JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I've connected a java project (using netbeans) to a MySQL database, but I'm having trouble inserting data.

If i use this code it inserts just fine:

```
String update = "insert into expenses(Expense,Cost,Purchase_Date,Description)\n" +
                "values('milk', 3.18, '2015-01-23','Grocery');";
```

but when i try and replace the insert values with these predefined values:

```
String ExpenseName;
Double ExpenseCost;
String ExpenseDate;
String ExpenseType;
```

and then use this code to insert the values:

```
String update = "insert into expenses(Expense,Cost,Purchase_Date,Description)\n" +
                "values('"+ExpenseName+"',"+ExpenseCost+",'"+ExpenseDate+"','"+ExpenseType+"');";
```

I get the error: SQLException: Column 'Cost' cannot be null

my cost field in my database is defined as decimal(15,2)

Even more annoyingly, when i try and use this code to update as a test:

```
String update = "insert into expenses(Expense,Cost,Purchase_Date,Description)\n" +
                "values('"+ExpenseName+"',3.18,'"+ExpenseDate+"','"+ExpenseType+"');";
```

i get another error saying:

```
 SQLException: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'Purchase_Date' at row 1
```

this is confuses me a lot because through the database i have no issues with updating the Purchase_Date field in the expenses table with a '2015-01-23'. if its of any use that field is of type date. perhaps it's because the date object in my java is string?

Comment: Why do you have "\n" in the SQL statement? That should be removed. You don't need it. Just put a space

Comment: Use query parameters.

Comment: Also, you should be using a `PreparedStatement` and not just concatenate a String. This allows for SQL injection. Here is a nice tutorial about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: Side note: `Decimal`/`Numeric` in SQL aren't floating-point values (like `float`/`double`), the have a specified precision.  The equivalent class in java is actually `BigDecimal`.  Using floating-point to store something that requires precise values can bite you; for example, `.1` can't be precisely stored, so `.1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 < 1.0`.  Eventually `16777216 + 1.0 = 16777216`, too (floats, doubles take longer).  For storing money, you want `BigDecimal` (or a dedicated currency library).

Answer (score 3):

You really should use a `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(
        "insert into expenses(Expense,Cost,Purchase_Date,Description)" +
        " values(?, ?, ?,?)");
pst.setString(1, ExpenseName);
pst.setDouble(2, ExpenseCost);
pst.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(ExpenseDate.getTime()));
pst.setString(4, ExpenseType);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Also, you should inititalize your variables properly.
Assuming that they are declared as fields, you should initialize them as :

```
String ExpenseName="SomeName";
Double ExpenseCost=1.8;
Date ExpenseDate=new Date();
String ExpenseType="Some Type";
```

Uninitialized variables could be the source of the `SQLException`, because `ExpenseName` and `ExpenseDate` would be concatenated as `"null"` in your SQL string.

Comment: And `Double` better be `double` (efficiency, double being the real primitive type).  And BigDecimal even better as double is an approximation, and `new BigDecimal("3.45")` will maintain a precision of 2.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to insert/ update data and not use String concatenation. This will not only help you with [formatting the data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDouble-int-double-) correctly but also protect you against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.